# How to iterate over a dictionary without updating key value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm facing with this case: I have a dictionary with this schema:

```
data = {
  "country": "",
  "lat": "",
  "long": ""
}
```

I want to populate this by iterating over a list of countries that I have and then append it to a list.
The result expected is:

```
countriesData = [
   {
      "country": "country1",
       ...
   },
   {
      "country": "country2",
       ...
   }
]
```

I run the next script but all I got is a list of dictionaries with repeated values in "country" key:
**Script**

```
for country in countries:
    dict["country"] = country
    countriesData.append(dict)
```

**output**

```
[
   {
      "country": "country1",
       ...
   },
   {
      "country": "country1",
       ...
   },
   { 
      "country": "country1"
   }
]
```

I'm new on python, I'll be grateful if you help me.
Regards

Comment: You keep appending **the same dict**, `countriesData.append(dict)`. Create a *new dict* on each iteration, maybe use a function, or just a dict literal but inside the loop body. Note, don't name your `dict` objects `dict`, that shadows the built-in name for the `dict` constructor

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried what you suggested and it works!!

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in data:
    toadd["country"] = item["country"]
    countriesData.append(toadd)
```

Expanding on the comment - you're adding the same thing to the new list.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you want to do here with the ellipsis. It seems like you want `countriesData` to have objects conforming to the schema at top, but your example code is only dealing with the `"country"` key.

Anyway, a more Python-y way to do what I think you want would be to use comprehensions, like so:

```
countriesData = [{"country": country} for country in countries]
```

This is essentially the same as:

```
countriesData = []
for country in countries:
    countriesData.append({"country": country})
```

Comment: I think using a list comprehension only adds to the confusion if the OP is new, it is worth showing the equivalent for-loop. And for-loops are plenty python-y